# Geometry - What's the approach when formulating a conditional statement about any given scenario?

Tags: geometry

How do I solve the prompt in the practice problem? I always struggle with deciding which should be the hypothesis, and which should be the conclusion.

[image: conditional_statement_practice]

In the first one, it seems to me that either "If $x=2$, then $9x+5=23$" or "If $9x+5=23$, then $x=2$" would be valid. I asked this question to someone, and was told that the point of formulating a conditional statement is mainly so the statement in question is valid. But, taking a look at 9, it seems we can't formulate any valid conditional statement:

**A) If you are in a band, then you play drums.**

*This is not true, because you could be the band guitarist.*

**B) If you play drums, then you are in a band.**

*This is not true, either, because you could be a solo player.*

I'm trying to go at it on my own, rehashing what I know, but I am really struggling.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Since it seems many types of reasoning can be involved in answering this question, I shall be more specific and say this is part of 10th grade "Proofs and Statements" course.

Edit 1: Here is another set of problems to make sure I am really understanding. Sorry for harping on this, but this chapter is really challenging my understanding of logic, which is exacerbated by the fact that many of the "if-then" statements seem too mechanical, and unlike the way we normally think.

[Practice 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7QiD.png)

The way I went about is: Given any particular rock, how would we go about figuring out what type it is? We'd (probably) take it to the laboratory, test for whether it is made of cooled molten rocks, pieces of other rocks, or by the changing of temperature. So, the conditional statement for 1, 2, 3 respectively would be: *If it is formed by the cooling of molten rocks, then it is an igneous rock; If it is formed by pieces from other rocks, then it is a sedimentary rock if it is formed by the changing of temperature, pressure, or chemistry, then it is a metaphoric rock.*

Is this correct?

Comment: Are the answers to exercises 8, 10, 11, and 12 clear to you?

Comment: To be clear, this question has nothing to do with geometry (though in the United States basic logic is often first taught in a geometry class), so the title shouldn't start with the word "geometry."

Comment: More or less, N.F; I picked 7 and 9, because they encapsulated my confusion the best.

Comment: What answers did you obtain for exercises 8, 10, 11, and 12?

Comment: 8) If today is Friday, then tomorrow is the weekend. 10) If two angles are right, then they are supplementary 11) If you are registered, then you are allowed to vote. 12) If two angles are complementary, then they measure 90 degrees.

Comment: I edited it; didn't know pressing enter would submit my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "$9x + 5 = 23$, because $x = 2$" in exercise 7 should be interpreted to mean "If $x = 2$, then $9x + 25 = 23$" since it means that the statement $9x + 5 = 23$ is true when $x = 2$.

The question about the band is, alas, ambiguous.

The answers you provided in the comments for exercises 8 and 10 are correct.

In exercise 12, you should have obtained "If two angles are complementary, then the sum of their measures is $90^\circ$."

Exercise 11 is tricky.  It is certainly true that if you are registered, then you are allowed to vote.  On the other hand, only those people who are registered are allowed to vote.  Hence, if you are allowed to vote, then you must be registered.  Therefore, I would interpret the statement "Only those people who are registered are allowed to vote" to mean "If you are allowed to vote, then you are registered."

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to walk me through your answers; I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the point of this exercise is simply to work with the *form* of conditional statements. Once you form a conditional statement, you can ask further whether it is true, or valid. However, as a purely formal exercise, the blanks can be filled in with any old statements. That seems to be what's going on here.

Your analysis of the band/drums statement seems correct. It's not going to be true, whichever way you put it together.

Comment: I think this settles my worries; I'll keep practicing to see if my understanding is solid yet. Is there ever a time (does the prompt say it?) when the exercise is concerned with both the "form" and the truth of the conditional statement?

Comment: Probably, yes. In actual mathematical proofs, we like for our statement to have correct form and also to be true, so that is the end goal.